# when to use line-continuation character and when not?

Tags: shell-script

I have been reading "The Linux command line book" and I have encountered this line continuation character and I am confused why do we use it with this find command:

```
find playground \
    \( \
        -type f \
        -not -perm 0600 \
        -exec chmod 0600 {} \; \
    \) \
    -or \
    \(
        other options...
    \)
```

***and*** why we didn't use it with this if statement :

```
if [ $x -eq 5 ]; then 
    echo "x equals 5."
else
    echo "x does not equal 5."
fi
```

Comment: `if`, `for`, `while`, `case` are [control structures](http://litux.nl/Reference/books/7213/ddu0071.html). The `\\` just allows you to continue a command in a new line.

Comment: @AdminBee
sorry I will take care next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a particularly complex example because some of the `\` there are what you're calling "line-continuation" but others are to protect characters so the shell doesn't interpret them and instead passes them to `find`. Specifically, the `\(`, `\)` and `\;` are there so that the shell doesn't interpret the escaped characters and passes them as-is to `find`. The rest, the `\` that aren't immediately before a non-space character are line continuation signals.

In general, if you want to break a command, you need the `\` *unless* you break on one of the ["list terminator"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222) characters. So, if you cut after one of these, you don't need the `\`:

```
; & && || | |& ;;
```

For example, `echo foo && echo bar` can be written as:

```
echo foo &&
echo bar
```

No need for `\`. Alternatively, the same thing can also be written as:

```
echo \
foo \
&&
echo \
bar
```

Note how I have used the `\` when cutting at places that are neither the end of  a command nor a list terminator.

If you cut a command anywhere else, you need the `\`. You don't need the `\` in the `if ... then ... else ...` example you show because there, you aren't cutting a command. Each command is on its own line, and that's fine. You only need the `\` if you want to break a *single* command onto multiple lines.

As @paul_pedant correctly pointed out in the comments, you can make the command much clearer if you use single quotes to escape things for `find`:

```
find playground \
    '(' \
        -type f \
        -not -perm 0600 \
        -exec chmod 0600 {} ';' \
    ')' \
    -or \
    '('
        other options...
    ')'
```

Comment: As terdon says, some of those \ are line continuations (essentially, they quote the newline), and some are plain quoting.  I really dislike that confusion. It is equally valid to quote the other find options as `'('   ')'   ';'` and to me it is more readable and thus less bug-prone.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant very good point! I added an example using single quotes. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon 
I know what they are but thanks for the detailed answer it helped so much but one more thing what makes these  `; & && || | |& ;;` characters special about these line continuation thing 
Is that because of the interpreter of the shell itself or I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: @MahmoudSalah yes, that's just how the shell's grammar works.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that because the former needs it, and the latter doesn't.

That `find` command is a *single* simple shell command, which just takes a number of distinct arguments, and has a structure of its own. Those arguments are just not meaningful to the shell, so it doesn't know there's e.g. a logical connection between the `(` and the `)`. The whole command could be written on a single line, it would just be harder to read.

Without the line continuations, `find` would run on `playground` with the default printing action, and then the shell would try to run the command `(` without arguments (or, the command `-type` in a subshell, if you were to remove the escape from the `(`, too):

```
find playground
    \(
        -type f 
        ...
```

On the other hand, the `if` compound statement is part of the shell syntax, and the shell knows what parts there are to expect. After the `then` there must be a command, and eventually an `else` or `fi`. The whole structure could also be written on a single line, but then we'd need to add semicolons before the `else` and the `fi`. (In the same way `echo foo; echo bar` requires to semicolon or a newline to be taken as two commands.)